# is it possible to use sql files as EF database migrations?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-migration, database-project

I'm using **EF6.0** and implementing my db with **SQLServerDatabaseProject**.
I want to use the EF Migration tools for Database migration. but since I have my database on DbProject I want all my migration files to be SQLFiles (not c#)
So I would like to know if EF supports this feature and if not, is it possible to write a new Migration class which keeps the EF features but works this way?

Please also consider that I don't want EF to generate my migrations but I would like to be able to use other migration commands such as update-database and ...

**==MORE DETAILS ABOUT THE QUESTION==**

I don't want to have c# classes load my sql files. The sql files must be saved for up and down migrations directly and be treated exactly as if they are the DbMigration classes. 
A simple example of Migrations dir would be something like this:

```
Migrations 
   -> up
       -> 201510060807125_alter-course-change-family.sql
       -> 201510060813136_alter-course-add-mark-column.sql
   -> down
       -> 201510060807125_alter-course-change-family.sql
       -> 201510060813136_alter-course-add-mark-column.sql
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply in the migration class use `SqlFile` extension method:

```
public partial class MyFancyMigration : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        SqlFile("myUpSQLFile.sql");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        SqlFile("myDownSQLFile.sql");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx for the answer, But I want to know if it's possible to  use SQL files for migrations instead of c# classes.

Answer (score -1):

Although you can use `SqlFile` method, I suggest you to write this on `Seed` method of your `Configuration.cs` file in your migration folder.

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationConfiguration<YourDbContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(YourDbContext context)
    {
        base.Seed(context);
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(FileReadAllText("migration.sql"));
    }
}
```

If you write migrations in `Up` method. It will be executed per each migration when you update the database, which I think you don't expect.

What you want is that your scripts run per each `Update-Database`. (Not per each migration in it)

Comment: Thanx for the answer, But I want to know if it's possible to use SQL files for migrations instead of c# classes